# start node process from docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    frontend:
        image: node:9
        working_dir: /dist
        command: PORT=8000 node /static/index.js
        volumes:
            - ./dist:/static
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        environment:
            NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

> Cannot start service frontend: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"PORT=8000\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the command to publish the port or make accessible by the host.
Only clause ports is enough.

```
ports:
  - 8000:8000
```

**note the double quote.**

If you need a environment variable, can use the clause environment

```
frontend:
  environment:
    - PORT=8000
```